# Counting sort Java - Unexpected results

Tags: java, sorting, counting-sort

```
class CountingSort {

    int[] csort(int[] arr) {
        int n = arr.length;
        int max = arr[0];
        int[] out = new int[n];
        for (int i : arr) {
            if (max < i) {
                max = i;
            }
        }
        int range = max + 1;
        int[] te = new int[range];
        for (int i = 0; i < range; ++i) {
            te[i] = 0;
        }
        for (int j = 1; j < n; j++) {
            te[arr[j]] = te[arr[j]] + 1;
        }
        // case1: {0,0,0,1,0,1,1,0,1,1}
        // case2: {0,0,0,1,0,1,1,0,1,1}
        for (int k = 1; k < range; ++k) {
            te[k] = te[k] + te[k - 1];
        }
        // case1: {0,0,0,1,1,2,3,3,4,5}
        // case2: {0,0,0,1,1,2,3,3,4,5}
        for (int l = n - 1; l >= 0; --l) {
            out[te[arr[l]]] = arr[l];
            te[arr[l]] = te[arr[l]] - 1;
        }
        return out;
    }

}
```

Above is the code for Counting Sort. Following are my observations

1. if the input array such that smallest is first element eg `{1, 6, 8, 3, 5, 9}` it gives the expected output `{1, 3, 5, 6, 8, 9}`
2. But if give the input array such that first element is not the smallest eg `{4, 6, 8, 3, 5, 9}` then the output has first element zero and one number goes missing. 
   I've tried but can't seem to find how this is happening.

Comment: That looks like great opportunity to learn how to use debugger. Step through your code and see which variable doesn't hold values you wanted.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The loop for counting occurrences doesn't iterate over all elements, you are skipping the `arr[0]`.

```
for (int j = 0; j < n; j++) {
    te[arr[j]] = te[arr[j]] + 1;
}
```

Besides, you could write it in a more "elegant" way:

```
for (int j = 0; j < n; ++te[arr[j]], ++j);
```

Comment: Also we have to change while getting output to out[te[arr[l]]-1] = arr[l];